# Why does sha1sum act differently with the same input?

Tags: linux, shell, digest, hashing

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of the sha1sum executable in some java code, however, in the process I've discovered that sha1sum appears to behave differently given the same input in two scenarios.

Assume input of '12345' without the single quotes and with no newline.

If I put this data into a file (file1) and run sha1sum from the command line:

```
$ sha1sum file1
8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964  file1
```

However, if I do this, I get a different result:

```
$ cat file1 | grep -vi foo | grep -vi bar | sha1sum
2672275fe0c456fb671e4f417fb2f9892c7573ba  -
```

Using the apache commons-codec jar, I'm able to read in file1, get it's contents, and perform a .shahex() on the content and get the first result.  However, I need to get the second result (due to legacy code) and I can't figure out why sha1sum is behaving differently, or what grep is doing to the input.

The system is running CentOS 5.4 with sha1sum 5.97

Any pointers?

Comment: i never recognized this, nice question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`grep` adds a newline.

```
$ hd file1
00000000  31 32 33 34 35                                    |12345|
00000005
$ grep -vi test <file1 | hd
00000000  31 32 33 34 35 0a                                 |12345.|
00000006
```

To get the same result you should add a single `\n`  at end of input if it is not present.

Comment: After taking the advice below and adding an extra newline, I think I have things working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Confirm the sequences are identical, first:

```
$ cat file1 | grep -vi foo | grep -vi bar > /tmp/junk
$ cmp file1 /tmp/junk
```

otherwise you'll just be chasing your tail.

Comment: This was brilliant advice, I had been printing out the results, but putting them into a file showed differences I didn't know about.  Unfortunately the answer above about the newline is still correct and ends up being the ultimate solution, so I can't mark your answer correct.  I would if I could mark two correct.

Comment: I upvoted whitequark, too, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Is your grep aliased to have --color? Have you checked the output of your pipeline without sha1sum in it?

Comment: `grep` only adds color (even with a --color switch) when writing to tty, i.e. when `isatty(1) == 1`. See `man 3 isatty`.

Comment: If it were aliased to `--color=always` for some reason, it ignores the tty check. Otherwise you're correct.

Comment: nope, it is not aliased